# Split a person name at a comma and capitalize each name component

Tags: python, string, list, split, capitalize

I have a name like this :

```
"DOE D, John"
```

and a name like this:

```
"DOE, Jane"
```

in the form of a string

I need to convert it to this:

```
"John D Doe"
```

and

```
"Jane Doe"
```

I have this so far:

```
name = "DOE, John"
name_list = []

comma = ","

for letter in name:
    name_list.append(letter)

index_comma = name_list.index(",")
last_name = name_list[:index_comma]
first_name = name_list[index_comma:]
print('The primary list is: ',name_list)
print("First half of list is ",first_name)
print("Second half of list is ",last_name)
new_name_list = first_name + last_name
for letter in new_name_list:
    if letter == comma:
        new_name_list.pop()
print(''.join(new_name_list))
```

but it returns this:

```
, JohnDO
```

How do I go about doing this in a clean and Pythonic way?

Comment: First step is making a formal definition of what you want to do. Which input format do you assume? People in general can have quite unusual names. Try to think of any sequence of characters and imagine how you could interpret it as a name, and what you want the output to be. Several words? Several commas? Commas inside quotes? Other punctuation? Emojis? Right-to-left markers? I am sure I forgot something.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following method:

```
>>> " ".join(reversed(" ".join("DOE D, John".split(",")).split())).title()
'John D Doe'

>>> " ".join(reversed(" ".join("DOE, Jane".split(",")).split())).title()
'Jane Doe'
```

- `.split(",")` splits the left and right sides of the comma
- The inner `" ".join` re-combines the components using spaces as separators
- `.split()` splits all words
- `reversed` reverses the word list
- The outer `" ".join` re-combines the reversed word list
- `.title()` capitalizes the first letter of each word

Answer (score 0):

how about

```
def convert_name_format(name):
    # split into parts
    parts = name.split(", ")
    first_part, first_name = parts
    first_parts = first_part.split(" ")
    # check for initial
    if len(first_parts) == 2:
        last_name, initial = first_parts
        if len(initial) > 1:
            new_format = f"{initial} {first_name} {last_name}"
        else:
            new_format = f"{first_name} {initial} {last_name}"
    else:
        new_format = f"{first_name} {first_part}"

    return new_format.title()

print(convert_name_format("DOE D, John"))
# John D Doe
print(convert_name_format("DOE, John"))
# John Doe
print(convert_name_format("DOE, John D"))
# John D Doe
print(convert_name_format("DOE John, D"))
# John D Doe
```

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked no matter what type of name I input. I tried "DOE, John D" with the other solutions but it gave "D John Doe".

Comment: @Programmer0403 updated